# Unable to access all session data

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am unable to access session data in the view, In below code I have set `session userdata` I can access `First name` and `last name` but not able to display `nationality` and `salutation`

Please check this code

**Controler:**

```
public function login_candidate()
{
    $data['error'] ="Invalid Username or Password";

    if($this->input->post())
    {
        $loginArray = array('candidate_email'=>$this->input->post('candidate_email'), 'candidate_password'=>md5($this->input->post('candidate_password')));

        $result = $this->Candidate_model->login_candidate($loginArray);

        if(count($result) > 0  AND is_object($result)){

            $session_data =array(
                'id'            ->$where['candidate_id'],
                'salutation'    ->$result->salutation,
                'candidate_first_name'  ->$result->candidate_first_name,
                'candidate_last_name'   ->$result->candidate_last_name,
                'nationaity'    ->$result->nationaity,

            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
            redirect('Home');
        }else{
            $this->load->view('frontend/header');
            $this->load->view('candidate/candidate_login',$data);
            $this->load->view('frontend/footer');
        }
    }
    else{
        $this->load->view('frontend/header');
        $this->load->view('candidate/candidate_login');
        $this->load->view('frontend/footer');
    }

}
```

**View:**

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
        <h2 class="font-weight-bold m-0">
            <?php echo $this->session->userdata('salutation') ?>
            <?php echo $this->session->userdata('candidate_first_name') ?>
            <?php echo $this->session->userdata('candidate_last_name') ?>
        </h2>
        <address class="m-0 pt-2 pl-0 pl-md-4 font-weight-light text-secondary">
            <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
            <?php echo $this->session->userdata('nationality') ?>
        </address>
    </div>
    <p class="h5 text-primary mt-2 d-block font-weight-light">
        Full-Stack Programmer
    </p>
    <p class="lead mt-4">All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet.</p>

    <section class="d-flex mt-5">
        <button class="btn btn-light bg-transparent mr-3 mb-3">
            <i class="fa fa-comments"></i>
            Private Message
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-light bg-transparent mr-3 mb-3">
            <i class="fa fa-warning"></i>
            Report User
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary mb-3">
            <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
            Hire Me
        </button>
    </section>

</div>
```

Here it does not display anything under salutation and nationality but at the same time first and last name are displayed

Comment: did you start your *session*  by defining in *config/autoload* or *$this->load->library('session')* on the top of function ? And also mention *session name* before define. Eg: `$this->session->set_userdata('login',$session_data);` It may help to to find out *session* information easily

Comment: from where you got `$where` here  `'id'            ->$where['candidate_id'],` ??? May be your data not stored in session.

Comment: please do `print_r($session_data);` what does it returns?

Comment: @Gulshan Yes i have started session already

Comment: replace `->` with `=>` .Due to this *error* data is not storing in *session*

Comment: @Gulshan i have changed the code as follow

Comment: `if(count($result) > 0){

    $this->session->set_userdata('salutation', $result[0]->salutation);
    $this->session->set_userdata('candidate_first_name', $result[0]->candidate_first_name);

Comment: @KUMAR after changing code i printed the array and it shows all data but not displaying on view Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1571898783 [salutation] => Mr. [candidate_first_name] => Sagar [candidate_last_name] => Cholke [nationaity] => Indian [candidate_email] => sagar@gmail.com [candidate_phone] => 8888888888 [candidate_job_title] => PHP Developar )

Answer (score 0):

I have updated Code as follow
Controler

```
if(count($result) > 0){



                $this->session->set_userdata('salutation', $result[0]->salutation);
                $this->session->set_userdata('candidate_first_name', $result[0]->candidate_first_name);
                $this->session->set_userdata('candidate_last_name', $result[0]->candidate_last_name);
                $this->session->set_userdata('nationaity', $result[0]->nationaity);
                $this->session->set_userdata('candidate_email', $result[0]->candidate_email);
                $this->session->set_userdata('candidate_phone', $result[0]->candidate_phone);
                $this->session->set_userdata('candidate_job_title', $result[0]->candidate_job_title);

                $session_data = $this->session->all_userdata(); 

                redirect('Home');
            }
```

And display data in view as

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['candidate_first_name'];?>
```

same for all by changing Variable name

Answer (score 0):

You will get all the session key which you set using userdata

```
$allSession = $this->session->userdata();
print_r($allSession);
```